# How do I remove hover animation from menu in WordPress website? [Bricksy Theme]

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, web-deployment-project

I am trying my hardest to find the option to remove the following hovering animation\effect from my WordPress website but it seems like its some sort of global variable or configuration - since I cant find an option to change it using the Bricksy Theme I am currently running.

the animation mentioned:

[image]

any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to remove the hover menu effect from your site?

Comment: yes, exactly.from the header specificly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the menu hover effect, add the following style to your template

```
.wp-block-navigation__container>.wp-block-navigation-item a:hover:before,
.wp-block-navigation__container>.wp-block-navigation-item a:hover:after {
    content: unset;
}
```

If it doesn't work, use it like this: `content:unset !important;`

Comment: how do I do that ? should I go to file manager, find the template file and add it -where exactly ?

Comment: @xxredxoctoberxx
Yes, inside the theme folder there is a file called style.css, you should put the css code I wrote in this file.

Comment: hey thank you, but it did not work. i did with content:unset !important; and with the content: unset;

Comment: @xxredxoctoberxx Are you sure you did it right? If you want, give me access and I will solve it for you

Comment: sure, can I send you the file?

Comment: @xxredxoctoberxx Yes, please send me the template

Comment: @xxredxoctoberxx If you can't send the theme, send the CSS file

Comment: how can i send it to you bro?

Comment: https://file.io/LjHp0K9C51TY

Comment: @xxredxoctoberxx There is a problem with the style file you sent, did you change it? There is html and js code inside the file. This is wrong

Comment: https://file.io/nHquvup48aGH this one is without the html and java (i downloaded from cpanel so they addded some extra stuff)

Comment: @xxredxoctoberxx check this https://file.io/RoZLloOTixFn

Comment: no, still nothing.

Comment: @xxredxoctoberxx Have you cleared your browser cache? Hit ctrl+f5 a few times, or test with Chrome browser's incognito mode

Comment: right XD thank you!!! it worked!!!! thank you so much brother!!!!

Comment: @xxredxoctoberxx you're welcome. good luck my friend